# Can we remove the old sandbox links?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, sandbox

At some point we decided to just have one global [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges). I think this is fine, I'm just concerned about all the links to old sandboxes that may confuse users, new and old alike.

When I'm not logged in, and viewing the Sandbox, I can see about 7 "Related" questions that also look like sandboxes:

[image]

They all link to the current Sandbox (unless you have the rep to see them). Despite this linking, it still seems like it could be misleading to users who are looking for the official Sandbox (we are *constantly* telling new users to "go to the Sandbox first, etc.").

Is there a way we can truly delete those old sandboxes so they don't show up?
(Is there any reason to keep them?)

Comment: Wow. The Sandbox when it only had 24 votes. Just. Wow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posts have been nuked. (Apparently merging a question into another one doesn't actually delete the original.)

Comment: Hmm, I can still seem them, whether logged in or no. (Also [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?rq=1) is not deleted.)

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies http://shouldiblamecaching.com